# How to get all records from the database via an endpoint in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the endpoint

```
http://localhost/mudb/unitedapi/
```

I need to get all the records in a json format from my table when i load the url in my browser. I can now only get a single record using the id from `http://localhost/mudb/unitedapi/1`. How can I get them all?

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule ^unitedapi/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*)$ api.php?player_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

My code

```
<?php

 header("Content-Type:application/json");
 if (isset($_GET['player_id']) && $_GET['player_id']!="") {
   include('db.php');
   $player_id = $_GET['player_id'];

   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `players` ");

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
   {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $fname = $row['fname'];
     $lname = $row['lname'];
     $shirtno = $row['shirtno'];
     $position = $row['position'];
     $response_code = $row['response_code'];
     $response_desc = $row['response_desc'];

     response($player_id, $fname,$lname,$shirtno,$position, 
 $response_code,$response_desc);
     mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else {
      response(NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, 200,"No Record Found");
    }
 } 
 else {
   response(NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL,400, "Invalid Request");
 }

 function response($player_id, $fname,$lname,$shirtno,$position, 
 $response_code,$response_desc)
 {
   $response['player_id'] = $player_id;
   $response['fname'] = $fname;
   $response['lname'] = $lname;
   $response['shirtno'] = $shirtno;
   $response['position'] = $position;
   $response['response_code'] = $response_code;
   $response['response_desc'] = $response_desc;

   $json_response = json_encode($response);
   echo $json_response;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`players\``...this code does not even select  by the ID anyway, it just selects them all, and then the PHP returns whatever the first row in the results happens to be.

Comment: To return all the rows, you need to loop until all the rows have been processed, add each row to an array, and then output that array at the end. There is no shortage of existing examples of this online already (because, unsurprisingly, returning multiple rows from a query is a very common requirement).

Comment: My bad, i've edited.

Comment: Ah sorry, my edit might have overwritten it. Can you edit again?

Comment: Sorry, i dont seem to get any of what you have said. Could you please share a link with a similar implementation

Comment: I just shared one. There are several others available to you via a simple google search. Basically you can either loop through all the rows, or use fetch_all()

Comment: your response function just makes your code uglier, it serves no purpose, simply just build out a var, i.e `$response` then send it, if you add 1 short line `exit(json_encode($response));`, or a long response( with a bunch of NULLs is no diff but much easier to follow

Comment: (For more info, every time you run `mysqli_fetch_array` (or mysqli_fetch_row`, or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`) it returns one row from the database. If there are no more rows, it returns null. So one technique is to loop until that returns null).

Comment: Lawrence is right, a lot of this code is redundant, just copying variables and using up memory when you could have used the $row data directly. And setting "response code" in a JSON object doesn't actually change your HTTP response code (which is what a RESTful API is supposed to do).